# Why does the electron impact ionization cross-section for atoms increase and then decrease as a function of incident electron energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, ionization-energy

The question really states it all and I haven't been able to find a source online or here that discusses the shapes of these characteristic ionization curves (argon curves shown below).  I would like to get an understanding of why the curves increase from the ionization potential (the necessity of the incident electron's energy exceeding the ionization potential is clear) and, more importantly, why they decrease with energy past about 3-5x the ionization potential.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my *guess*.

The cross-section rises suddenly as the incident electron energy approximates the ionization energy, just as you would expect. But as the electron energy rises beyond that point, its effective wavelength gets progressively shorter which reduces its chances of interacting with another electron in the vicinity of the argon atom. In the limit of a *very* energetic electron, it zips right through the electron cloud surrounding the nucleus and instead begins to interact with nucleus itself. Mayhem ensues, and carnage results.